# Mac/iPad invalid provisioning profile match

Tags: macos, ipad

I'm getting an error building my app in xcode. It's saying:

A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'MyGameName' could not be found.

In xcode if I go to Window->Organizer, under my connected iPad and Provisioning Profiles I have my profile. Now the profile name isn't the same as my game name (I assume that's fine). My understanding is the provisioning profile bundles a couple things together. One of those being the App ID. When I created this App ID it was related to my game. In Organizer with this profile there is a column for App Identifier but it's some random numbers. What is that all about and I assume my Bundle ID in xcode shouldn't be this random numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the project settings? Application ID has to be similar to one you've obtained from dev center for your app.

Comment: So I was able to get it to run. In Organizer I ad to right click on my iPad and select 'Add device to Provisioning Portal' While I was going through the wizard for all this stuff I guess it never added it to the protal. Once I did this, it created another provisioning profile for me, that looks exactly the same as the one I did, but guessing because my device wasn't registered it wasn't working.